# Cygwin compiling program using libwebrtc-audio-processing-devel

Tags: c++, cygwin, webrtc

I want to use the VAD module of webrtc, compiling on Cygwin.
Cygwin has some packages for this: [packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji7je.png)

I installed the selected packages and want to work out how to get things compiling. I've included what I've tried so far below. Am I taking the right approach to this? Or should I continue in a different way? I'm an amateur when it comes to c code.

main.cpp

```
int main() {
    AudioProcessing* apm;
}
```

Compiling

```
$ g++ main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:3:2: error: ‘AudioProcessing’ was not declared in this scope
  AudioProcessing* apm;
  ^
main.cpp:3:19: error: ‘apm’ was not declared in this scope
  AudioProcessing* apm;
```

So I need to include some headers and link a dll to provide the implementation I'm guessing.

```
$ ls /usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/
base/            common_types.h   system_wrappers/
common.h         modules/         typedefs.h

$ find / -name "*rtc*dll"
/bin/cygsmartcols-1.dll
/bin/cygwebrtc_audio_processing-1.dll
/usr/bin/cygsmartcols-1.dll
/usr/bin/cygwebrtc_audio_processing-1.dll
```

I found the header containing class AudioProcessing in audio_processing.h

main.cpp

```
#include "audio_processing.h"
int main() {
    AudioProcessing* apm;
}
```

Compiling

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o main -L/bin/ -lcygwebrtc_audio_processing-1 -I/usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/modules/audio_processing/include/
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
/usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/modules/audio_processing/include/audio_processing.h:22:35: fatal error: webrtc/base/arraysize.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Sorry if this seems obvious, we all have to start somewhere.

**Results of discussion:**

The following resulted in a successful compilation of a trivial program using libwertc-audio-processing-devel on Cygwin.

```
$ cat main.cpp
#include "webrtc/modules/audio_processing/include/audio_processing.h"
int main() {
        webrtc::AudioProcessing* apm;
}
$ g++ main.cpp -o main -I/usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/ -DWEBRTC_WIN -std=gnu++11 -L/bin/ -lcygwebrtc_audio_processing-1
```

Comment: try  with `-lwebrtc_audio_processing`

Comment: @matzeri
That didn't do it either.

Output:
`$ g++ main.cpp -o main -L/bin/ -lwebrtc_audio_processing -I/usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/modules/audio_processing/include/
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
/usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/modules/audio_processing/include/audio_processing.h:22:35: fatal error: webrtc/base/arraysize.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

Answer (score 1):

looks at the package contents:

https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/libwebrtc-audio-processing-devel/libwebrtc-audio-processing-devel-0.3-1

```
2016-07-28 08:48           0 usr/include/
2016-07-28 08:48           0 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/
2016-07-28 08:48           0 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/
2016-07-28 08:48           0 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/base/
2016-07-28 08:48        1190 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/base/arraysize.h
2016-07-28 08:48        2257 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/base/basictypes.h
2016-07-28 08:48       10507 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/base/checks.h
2016-07-28 08:48        1407 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/base/constructormagic.h
2016-07-28 08:48        3572 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/base/maybe.h
2016-07-28 08:48        1248 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/base/platform_file.h
2016-07-28 08:48        3343 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/common.h
2016-07-28 08:48       27807 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/common_types.h
2016-07-28 08:48           0 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/modules/
2016-07-28 08:48           0 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/modules/audio_processing/
2016-07-28 08:48           0 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/modules/audio_processing/beamformer/
2016-07-28 08:48        3534 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/modules/audio_processing/beamformer/array_util.h
2016-07-28 08:48           0 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/modules/audio_processing/include/
2016-07-28 08:48       38576 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/modules/audio_processing/include/audio_processing.h
2016-07-28 08:48           0 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/modules/interface/
2016-07-28 08:48       27021 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/modules/interface/module_common_types.h
2016-07-28 08:48           0 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/system_wrappers/
2016-07-28 08:48           0 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/system_wrappers/include/
2016-07-28 08:48        3706 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/system_wrappers/include/trace.h
2016-07-28 08:48        3682 usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/typedefs.h
2016-07-28 08:48           0 usr/lib/
2016-07-28 08:48     1360018 usr/lib/libwebrtc_audio_processing.dll.a
2016-07-28 08:48           0 usr/lib/pkgconfig/
2016-07-28 08:48         317 usr/lib/pkgconfig/webrtc-audio-processing.pc
```

the include directive is likely only

```
-I/usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing
```

Comment: That does seem right, I've seen code instances from different 'copies' of the library referencing headers starting with the webrtc folder (which is in webrtc_audio_processing). I modified my simple main.cpp to accomodate for this change and compiled. Now we have some new output, see [here](http://pastebin.com/WDh6z1BQ). One part of the output was `/usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/base/platform_file.h:27:2: error: #error Unsupported platform
 #error Unsupported platform`, but if this didn't compile on cygwin why would it be available as a package?

Comment: Using the headers this way (`#include <webrtc/...>`) is, in fact, correct. You might need to also add `-DWEBRTC_WIN` to your build flags to signal to the headers that you're building for Windows.

Comment: That helped!
There was another error:
`/usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/webrtc/base/maybe.h:34:7: warning: override controls (override/final) only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11`
that required me to add -std=c++11
Now I have:
`$ g++ main.cpp -o main -L/bin/ -lcygwebrtc_audio_processing-1 -I/usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/ -DWEBRTC_WIN -std=c++11`
And the following [output](http://pastebin.com/wS0Yp6qN).
I'm not sure why this M_PI variable has not been declared, trying to work it out.

Comment: [audio_processing.h](https://puu.sh/usnZu/edf4644527.png)
 looks like it should be good since it has #define _USE_MATH_DEFINES before the math.h include.

[array_util.h](https://puu.sh/uso0G/eedef5cb03.png)
 does not have #define _USE_MATH_DEFINES before cmath.h, but adding it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Try using `-std=gnu++11` instead?

Comment: Boom! That resolved the MATH_PI issue. Then I just needed to reference the correct name space on the AudioProcessing definition (webrtc::AudioProcessing) and it's compiling! I'll have to put together a complete program and see how that goes next.