# Increasing microphone gain programmatically

Tags: c++, signal-processing, microphone, portaudio

I'm trying to increase the gain of my microphone for VOIP scenarios.
I'm using PortAudio to acquire an input stream (with samples of type paFloat32), I'm multiplying these values by a float, then passing the resultant stream to an output device.
Note: I'm passing it to a virtual output device that automatically redirects to a virtual input device (program: VB-Cable), which VOIP applications can use as the microphone input with gain applied.

I'm wondering if there are better ways to increase gain of a signal that maintain quality better.

I've read that it's better to perform such gain calculations by first converting the input to a higher precision format, performing the gain multiplication in this format, apply clipping, then cast back down to the original.
I'm not sure how to do this with PortAudio's paFloat32 type, I've included my attempt commented out in the source code. When I enable it there is notable noise issues even with gain set to 1.

Dependencies: `tinycon, PortAudio`

Compiling: `g++ main.cpp tinycon.cpp -o main -L./ -lcygportaudio-2 -lrt -lm -pthread  -std=c++11`

Code:

```
#include "portaudio.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include "tinycon.h"

#define SAMPLE_RATE       (44100)
#define FRAMES_PER_BUFFER   (441)
#define DITHER_FLAG           (1)

#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paFloat32
#define SAMPLE_SIZE (4)
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE  (0)
#define PRINTF_S_FORMAT "%f"

/*******************************************************************/
double multiplier = 1.0;
double multiplierStep = 0.1;
int main(int argc, char **argv);
int xrun(PaStream *stream, int err, char* sampleBlock);
void error1(PaStream *stream, char* sampleBlock);
void error2(PaStream *stream, int err);
void listDevices();

// Use tinycon and a second thread for non blocking input
class tcon : public tinyConsole
{
public:
        tcon (std::string s): tinyConsole(s) {;}

        int hotkeys(char c)
        {
                if (c == 's') {
                        if (multiplier >= (0+multiplierStep)) {
                                multiplier -= multiplierStep;
                        }
                        printf( "Multiplier: %f\n", multiplier );
                        return 1;
                }
                if (c == 'w') {
                        multiplier += multiplierStep;
                        printf( "Multiplier: %f\n", multiplier );
                        return 1;
                }
                return 0;
        }
};
int inputThread() {
        tcon tc (std::string(""));
        tc.run();
}

void listDevices() {
        int i, numDevices, defaultDisplayed;
        const PaDeviceInfo *deviceInfo;

        Pa_Initialize();

        numDevices = Pa_GetDeviceCount();

        printf( "Number of devices = %d\n", numDevices );
        int isInputDevice = 0;
        for( i=0; i<numDevices; i++ )
        {
                deviceInfo = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( i );
                int isInputDevice = (deviceInfo->maxInputChannels > 0);
                printf( "%sDeviceID: %d, Name: %s\n", (isInputDevice ? "Input" : "Output"), i, deviceInfo->name);
        }
        fprintf (stderr, "Press any key to close\n");
        getch();
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
        int c;
        int inputDeviceId = -1;
        int outputDeviceId = -1;
        opterr = 0;
        const char* helpMessage =
                "-h : show this help message\n"
                "-i <int> : select the INPUT DEVICE by id\n"
                "-o <int> : select the OUPUT DEVICE by id\n"
                "-m <double> : SIGNAL MULTIPLIER\n"
                "-s <double> : SIGNAL MULTIPLIER STEP (press w or s while console focused to go up and down by this ammount.\n"
                "-d : list devices\n";

        while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "i:o:l:m:s:hd")) != -1) {
                switch (c) {
                        case 'i':
                                inputDeviceId = atoi(optarg);
                                break;
                        case 'o':
                                outputDeviceId = atoi(optarg);
                                break;
                        case 'm':
                                multiplier = atof(optarg);
                                break;
                        case 's':
                                multiplierStep = atof(optarg);
                                break;
                        case 'd':
                                listDevices();
                                return 0;
                        case '?':
                                if (isprint (optopt))
                                        fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
                                else
                                        fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n", optopt);
                        case 'h':
                                fprintf (stderr, helpMessage);
                                fprintf (stderr, "Press any key to close\n");
                                getch();
                                return 1;
                        default:
                        abort ();
                }
        }

        // Start non blocking input thread
        std::thread nonBlockingInputThread(inputThread);


    PaStreamParameters inputParameters, outputParameters;
    PaStream *stream = NULL;
    PaError err;
    const PaDeviceInfo* inputInfo;
    const PaDeviceInfo* outputInfo;
    char *sampleBlock = NULL;
    int i;
    int numBytes;
    int numChannels;

    err = Pa_Initialize();
    if( err != paNoError ) error2(stream, err);

    inputParameters.device = (inputDeviceId == -1) ? Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice() : inputDeviceId; /* default input device */
    inputInfo = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( inputParameters.device );
    outputParameters.device = (outputDeviceId == -1) ? Pa_GetDefaultOutputDevice() : outputDeviceId; /* default output device */
    outputInfo = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( outputParameters.device );

        numChannels = inputInfo->maxInputChannels < outputInfo->maxOutputChannels
                ? inputInfo->maxInputChannels : outputInfo->maxOutputChannels;

    inputParameters.channelCount = numChannels;
    inputParameters.sampleFormat = PA_SAMPLE_TYPE;
    inputParameters.suggestedLatency = inputInfo->defaultHighInputLatency ;
    inputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;
    printf( "Input device # %d.\n", inputParameters.device );
    printf( "    Name: %s\n", inputInfo->name );


        outputParameters.channelCount = numChannels;
        outputParameters.sampleFormat = PA_SAMPLE_TYPE;
        outputParameters.suggestedLatency = outputInfo->defaultHighOutputLatency;
        outputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;
    printf( "Output device # %d.\n", outputParameters.device );
    printf( "    Name: %s\n", outputInfo->name );

    /* -- setup -- */

    err = Pa_OpenStream(
              &stream,
              &inputParameters,
              &outputParameters,
              SAMPLE_RATE,
              FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
              paClipOff,      /* we won't output out of range samples so don't bother clipping them */
              NULL, /* no callback, use blocking API */
              NULL ); /* no callback, so no callback userData */
    if( err != paNoError ) error2(stream, err);

    numBytes = FRAMES_PER_BUFFER * numChannels * SAMPLE_SIZE ;
    sampleBlock = (char *) malloc( numBytes );
    if( sampleBlock == NULL )
    {
        printf("Could not allocate record array.\n");
        error1(stream, sampleBlock);
    }

    err = Pa_StartStream( stream );
    if( err != paNoError ) error1(stream, sampleBlock);


        while (1) {
        // You may get underruns or overruns if the output is not primed by PortAudio.
        err = Pa_ReadStream( stream, sampleBlock, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER );
        if( err ) xrun(stream, err, sampleBlock);

                int blockIndex;
                float* sampleBlockShort = (float*)sampleBlock;
                for (blockIndex = 0; blockIndex < FRAMES_PER_BUFFER; blockIndex++) {
                        /*
                        double dSample = (double)sampleBlockShort[blockIndex];
                        dSample *= multiplier;
                        if (dSample > 32767.0) dSample = 32767.0;
                        if (dSample < -32768.0) dSample = -32768.0;
                        sampleBlockShort[blockIndex] = (short)dSample;
                        */
                        sampleBlockShort[blockIndex] *= multiplier;
                }

                err = Pa_WriteStream( stream, sampleBlock, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER );
                if( err ) xrun(stream, err, sampleBlock);
    }
    printf("Wire off.\n"); fflush(stdout);

    err = Pa_StopStream( stream );
    if( err != paNoError ) error1(stream, sampleBlock);

    free( sampleBlock );

    Pa_Terminate();
    return 0;

}

int xrun(PaStream *stream, int err, char* sampleBlock) {
    printf("err = %d\n", err); fflush(stdout);
    if( stream ) {
       Pa_AbortStream( stream );
       Pa_CloseStream( stream );
    }
    free( sampleBlock );
    Pa_Terminate();
    if( err & paInputOverflow )
       fprintf( stderr, "Input Overflow.\n" );
    if( err & paOutputUnderflow )
       fprintf( stderr, "Output Underflow.\n" );
    return -2;
}

void error1(PaStream *stream, char* sampleBlock) {
    free( sampleBlock );
    exit(-1);
}

void error2(PaStream *stream, int err) {
    if( stream ) {
       Pa_AbortStream( stream );
       Pa_CloseStream( stream );
    }
    Pa_Terminate();
    fprintf( stderr, "An error occured while using the portaudio stream\n" );
    fprintf( stderr, "Error number: %d\n", err );
    fprintf( stderr, "Error message: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText( err ) );
    exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: Guess that clipping float is to limit multiplication to -1.0  if it less than -1.0 and to 1.0 if it greater than 1.0. The same way how you did for short. Have you tried to copy input data to output without any multiplication? You shoud hear good voice without issues. And guess you know, that increasing volume the same way, you also increase noise from input signal.

Comment: @alexander Copying input to output directly produces no quality issues. I did know that increasing gain would increase noise, but I didn't think of it in terms of amplifying the noise already present, which makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Portaudio use interleaved data format in your config.  So if 'numChannels > 1' you iterate over part of buffer and some samples leaves unchanged. So you might hear noise issues. Change loop condition to 'blockIndex < FRAMES_PER_BUFFER * numChannels'. Commented out attempt to increase gain looks fine. And current attempt looks fine except lost clipping (-1.0 .. 1.0). I'd be using you first solution to increase gain, because using paFloat32 you add extra work to portaudio to convert from int16 to paFloat32 and again to int16 without benefits.

Comment: Ooops! I guess that means I only applied gain to the first half of both channels of the buffer, surprised I let that one slip.

Comment: `And current attempt looks fine except lost clipping (-1.0 .. 1.0).`
So should I be doing something like:

`float sampleWithGain = sampleBlockShort[blockIndex];
sampleWithGain *= multiplier;
sampleWithGain = (sampleWithGain > 1) ? 1 
  : (sampleWithGain < 1) ? -1 
  : sampleWithGain;
sampleBlokcShort[blockIndex] = sampleWithGain;`

Comment: `using paFloat32 you add extra work to portaudio to convert from int16 to paFloat32`
Do audio systems typically work with int16 and when I'm telling PortAudio to use paFlot32 I'm making extra conversions occur?
If thats the case this makes sense to me, otherwise I have no idea what you've noticed.
Also if I use paInt16, my multipliers have to be shorts (instead of floats). This gives less control.

Comment: "Also if I use paInt16, my multipliers have to be shorts (instead of floats)." You can use [Fixed point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) for representing fractional multipliers. For example 2.3 can be expressed like 2.3*256=588 (256 is 1<<8). Than you can calculate each sample as snew=(sample*588) >> 8.

Comment: "Do audio systems typically work with int16 and when I'm telling PortAudio to use paFlot32 I'm making extra conversions occur?" I guess they do. I think that portaudio won't convert int16 to paFlot32 unless it requested to do that. For example, signal from microphone come as int16.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can use the webrtc library for this as well. It comes with noise suppression which is handy. I don't understand what compression_gain_db and target_level_dbfs actually do, but setting them to their highest values seems to apply the most gain. Working in int16 as suggested by @alexander resolved many issues to my custom solution and fixing up the loop to go over the entire buffer helped as well. Both webrtc's solution and my own can be played with in realtime with the following example code.

Code example included below.

```
$ ./main.exe -h
-h : show this help message
-i <int> : select the INPUT DEVICE by id
-o <int> : select the OUPUT DEVICE by id
-c <int [0,90]> : compression_gain_db
-t <int [0, 31]> : target_level_dbfs
-g <0 or 1> : toggle webrtc gain control on and off (1 by default)
-k <0 or 1> : toggle custom gain control on and off (1 by default)
-f <int [1, maxInt]> : customGainControlFactor
-q <int [0, 3]> : webrtc noise supression level, high is more suppression
-e <0 or 1> : toggle webrtc noise suppression on and off (1 by default)
-d : list devices

Real time controls:
compression_gain_db            UP_KEY='a' DOWN_KEY='s'
target_dbfs_level              UP_KEY='d' DOWN_KEY='f'
webrtcGainControlEnabled                           TOGGLE_KEY='g'
webrtcNoiseSuppressionLevel    UP_KEY='q' DOWN_KEY='w'
webrtcNoiseSuppressionEnabled                      TOGGLE_KEY='e'
customGainFactor               UP_KEY='h' DOWN_KEY='j'
customGainFactorEnabled                            TOGGLE_KEY='k'
Press any key to close
```

Dependencies: `tinycon, PortAudio, libwebrtc-audio-processing-devel`

Note: I'm working on cygwin, if you have trouble with libwebrtc see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554850/cygwin-compiling-program-using-libwebrtc-audio-processing-devel)

Compiling: `g++ main.cpp tinycon.cpp -o main -L./ -lcygportaudio-2 -lrt -lm -pthread -I/usr/include/webrtc_audio_processing/ -DWEBRTC_WIN -DWEBRTC`

main.cpp

```
#include "portaudio.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include "tinycon.h"

#include "webrtc/modules/audio_processing/include/audio_processing.h"
#include "webrtc/modules/interface/module_common_types.h"
#include "webrtc/system_wrappers/include/trace.h"
using webrtc::AudioProcessing;
using webrtc::AudioFrame;
using webrtc::GainControl;
using webrtc::NoiseSuppression;

#define SAMPLE_RATE       (32000)
#define FRAMES_PER_BUFFER   (320)
#define DITHER_FLAG           (0)

#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE paInt16
#define SAMPLE_SIZE (2)
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE  (0)
#define PRINTF_S_FORMAT "%d"

/*******************************************************************/
int customGainFactor = 1;
int customGainFactorStep = 1;
bool customGainControlEnabled = true;
int compression_gain_db = 1;
int compression_gain_dbStep = 1;
int target_level_dbfs = 1;
int target_level_dbfsStep = 1;
bool webrtcGainControlEnabled = true;
bool webrtcNoiseSuppressionEnabled = true;
int webrtcNoiseSuppressionLevel = 1;
int main(int argc, char **argv);
int xrun(PaStream *stream, int err, char* sampleBlock);
void error1(PaStream *stream, char* sampleBlock);
void error2(PaStream *stream, int err);
void listDevices();
webrtc::NoiseSuppression::Level webrtcNoiseSuppressionLevelToEnum(int level);
// Use tinycon and a second thread for non blocking input
class tcon : public tinyConsole
{
public:
        tcon (std::string s): tinyConsole(s) {;}

        int hotkeys(char c)
        {
                if (c == 'a') {
                        if (compression_gain_db >= (0+compression_gain_dbStep)) {
                                compression_gain_db -= compression_gain_dbStep;
                        }
                        printf( "Compression_gain_db: %d\n", compression_gain_db );
                        return 1;
                }
                if (c == 's') {
                        if (compression_gain_db <= (90-compression_gain_dbStep)) {
                                compression_gain_db += compression_gain_dbStep;
                        }
                        printf( "Compression_gain_db: %d\n", compression_gain_db );
                        return 1;
                }
                if (c == 'd') {
                        if (target_level_dbfs >= (0+target_level_dbfsStep)) {
                                target_level_dbfs -= target_level_dbfsStep;
                        }
                        printf( "target_level_dbfs: %d\n", target_level_dbfs );
                        return 1;
                }
                if (c == 'f') {
                        if (target_level_dbfs <= (31-target_level_dbfsStep)) {
                                target_level_dbfs += target_level_dbfsStep;
                        }
                        printf( "target_level_dbfs: %d\n", target_level_dbfs );
                        return 1;
                }
                if (c == 'g') {
                        webrtcGainControlEnabled = !webrtcGainControlEnabled;
                        printf("webrtcGainControlEnabled: %s\n", (webrtcGainControlEnabled) ? "true" : "false");
                        return 1;
                }
                if (c == 'h') {
                        if (customGainFactor >= (1+customGainFactorStep)) {
                                customGainFactor -= customGainFactorStep;
                        }
                        printf( "customGainFactor: %d\n", customGainFactor );
                        return 1;
                }
                if (c == 'j') {
                        customGainFactor += customGainFactorStep;
                        printf( "customGainFactor: %d\n", customGainFactor );
                        return 1;
                }
                if (c == 'k') {
                        customGainControlEnabled = !customGainControlEnabled;
                        printf("customGainControlEnabled: %s\n", (customGainControlEnabled) ? "true" : "false");
                        return 1;
                }
                if (c == 'q') {
                        if (webrtcNoiseSuppressionLevel <= (3-1)) {
                                webrtcNoiseSuppressionLevel += 1;
                        }
                        printf( "webrtcNoiseSuppressionLevel: %d\n", webrtcNoiseSuppressionLevel );
                        return 1;
                }
                if (c == 'w') {
                        if (webrtcNoiseSuppressionLevel >= (0+1)) {
                                webrtcNoiseSuppressionLevel -= 1;
                        }
                        printf( "webrtcNoiseSuppressionLevel: %d\n", webrtcNoiseSuppressionLevel );
                        return 1;
                }
                if (c == 'e') {
                        webrtcNoiseSuppressionEnabled = !webrtcNoiseSuppressionEnabled;
                        printf("webrtcNoiseSuppressionEnabled: %s\n", (webrtcNoiseSuppressionEnabled) ? "true" : "false");
                        return 1;
                }
                return 0;
        }
};
int inputThread() {
        tcon tc (std::string(""));
        tc.run();
}

void listDevices() {
        int i, numDevices, defaultDisplayed;
        const PaDeviceInfo *deviceInfo;

        Pa_Initialize();

        numDevices = Pa_GetDeviceCount();

        printf( "Number of devices = %d\n", numDevices );
        int isInputDevice = 0;
        for( i=0; i<numDevices; i++ )
        {
                deviceInfo = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( i );
                int isInputDevice = (deviceInfo->maxInputChannels > 0);
                printf( "%sDeviceID: %d, Name: %s\n", (isInputDevice ? "Input" : "Output"), i, deviceInfo->name);
        }
        fprintf (stderr, "Press any key to close\n");
        getch();
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
        int c;
        int inputDeviceId = -1;
        int outputDeviceId = -1;
        opterr = 0;
        const char* helpMessage =
                "-h : show this help message\n"
                "-i <int> : select the INPUT DEVICE by id\n"
                "-o <int> : select the OUPUT DEVICE by id\n"
                "-c <int [0,90]> : compression_gain_db\n"
                "-t <int [0, 31]> : target_level_dbfs\n"
                "-g <0 or 1> : toggle webrtc gain control on and off (1 by default)\n"
                "-k <0 or 1> : toggle custom gain control on and off (1 by default)\n"
                "-f <int [1, maxInt]> : customGainControlFactor\n"
                "-q <int [0, 5]> : webrtc noise supression level, high is more suppression\n"
                "-e <0 or 1> : toggle webrtc noise suppression on and off (1 by default)\n"
                "-d : list devices\n"
                "\n"
                "Real time controls:\n"
                "compression_gain_db            UP_KEY='a' DOWN_KEY='s'\n"
                "target_dbfs_level              UP_KEY='d' DOWN_KEY='f'\n"
                "webrtcGainControlEnabled                           TOGGLE_KEY='g'\n"
                "webrtcNoiseSuppressionLevel    UP_KEY='q' DOWN_KEY='w'\n"
                "webrtcNoiseSuppressionEnabled                      TOGGLE_KEY='e'\n"
                "customGainFactor               UP_KEY='h' DOWN_KEY='j'\n"
                "customGainFactorEnabled                            TOGGLE_KEY='k'\n";

        while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "i:o:c:t:g:k:f:w:q:hd")) != -1) {
                switch (c) {
                        case 'i':
                                inputDeviceId = atoi(optarg);
                                break;
                        case 'o':
                                outputDeviceId = atoi(optarg);
                                break;
                        case 'c':
                                compression_gain_db = atoi(optarg);
                                break;
                        case 't':
                                target_level_dbfs = atoi(optarg);
                                break;
                        case 'g':
                                webrtcGainControlEnabled = (atoi(optarg) == 1) ? true : false;
                                break;
                        case 'f':
                                customGainFactor = atoi(optarg);
                                break;
                        case 'k':
                                customGainControlEnabled = (atoi(optarg) == 1) ? true : false;
                                break;
                        case 'w':
                                webrtcNoiseSuppressionLevel = atoi(optarg);
                                break;
                        case 'e':
                                webrtcNoiseSuppressionEnabled = (atoi(optarg) == 1) ? true : false;
                                break;
                        case 'd':
                                listDevices();
                                return 0;
                        case '?':
                                if (isprint (optopt))
                                        fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
                                else
                                        fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n", optopt);
                        case 'h':
                                fprintf (stderr, helpMessage);
                                fprintf (stderr, "Press any key to close\n");
                                getch();
                                return 1;
                        default:
                        abort ();
                }
        }

        // Start non blocking input thread
        std::thread nonBlockingInputThread(inputThread);


    PaStreamParameters inputParameters, outputParameters;
    PaStream *stream = NULL;
    PaError err;
    const PaDeviceInfo* inputInfo;
    const PaDeviceInfo* outputInfo;
    char *sampleBlock = NULL;
    int i;
    int numBytes;
    int numChannels;

    err = Pa_Initialize();
    if( err != paNoError ) error2(stream, err);

    inputParameters.device = (inputDeviceId == -1) ? Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice() : inputDeviceId; /* default input device */
    inputInfo = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( inputParameters.device );
    outputParameters.device = (outputDeviceId == -1) ? Pa_GetDefaultOutputDevice() : outputDeviceId; /* default output device */
    outputInfo = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( outputParameters.device );

        numChannels = inputInfo->maxInputChannels < outputInfo->maxOutputChannels
                ? inputInfo->maxInputChannels : outputInfo->maxOutputChannels;

    inputParameters.channelCount = numChannels;
    inputParameters.sampleFormat = PA_SAMPLE_TYPE;
    inputParameters.suggestedLatency = inputInfo->defaultHighInputLatency ;
    inputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;
    printf( "Input device # %d.\n", inputParameters.device );
    printf( "    Name: %s\n", inputInfo->name );


        outputParameters.channelCount = numChannels;
        outputParameters.sampleFormat = PA_SAMPLE_TYPE;
        outputParameters.suggestedLatency = outputInfo->defaultHighOutputLatency;
        outputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;
    printf( "Output device # %d.\n", outputParameters.device );
    printf( "    Name: %s\n", outputInfo->name );

    /* -- setup -- */

    err = Pa_OpenStream(
              &stream,
              &inputParameters,
              &outputParameters,
              SAMPLE_RATE,
              FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
              paClipOff,      /* we won't output out of range samples so don't bother clipping them */
              NULL, /* no callback, use blocking API */
              NULL ); /* no callback, so no callback userData */
    if( err != paNoError ) error2(stream, err);

    numBytes = FRAMES_PER_BUFFER * numChannels * SAMPLE_SIZE ;
    sampleBlock = (char *) malloc( numBytes );
    if( sampleBlock == NULL )
    {
        printf("Could not allocate record array.\n");
        error1(stream, sampleBlock);
    }

        // Configure webrtc::audioprocessing
        int webrtcErr;
        AudioProcessing* apm = AudioProcessing::Create();

        apm->high_pass_filter()->Enable(true);

        apm->noise_suppression()->set_level(webrtcNoiseSuppressionLevelToEnum(webrtcNoiseSuppressionLevel));
        apm->noise_suppression()->Enable(webrtcNoiseSuppressionEnabled);

        apm->gain_control()->set_mode(apm->gain_control()->kFixedDigital);
        apm->gain_control()->set_compression_gain_db(compression_gain_db);
        apm->gain_control()->set_target_level_dbfs(target_level_dbfs);
        apm->gain_control()->Enable(webrtcGainControlEnabled);

    err = Pa_StartStream( stream );
    if( err != paNoError ) error1(stream, sampleBlock);

        while (1) {
        // You may get underruns or overruns if the output is not primed by PortAudio.
        err = Pa_ReadStream( stream, sampleBlock, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER );
        if( err ) xrun(stream, err, sampleBlock);

                // Run custom gain solution
                if (customGainControlEnabled) {
                        int blockIndex;
                        short* sampleBlockShort = (short*)sampleBlock;
                        for (blockIndex = 0; blockIndex < FRAMES_PER_BUFFER*numChannels; blockIndex++) {
                                        int iSample = (int)sampleBlockShort[blockIndex];
                                        iSample *= customGainFactor;
                                        if (iSample > std::numeric_limits<short>::max())
                                        iSample =
                                                  (iSample > std::numeric_limits<short>::max()) ? std::numeric_limits<short>::max()
                                                : (iSample < std::numeric_limits<short>::min()) ? std::numeric_limits<short>::min()
                                                : iSample;
                                        sampleBlockShort[blockIndex] = (short)iSample;
                        }
                }

                // Apply webrtc gain and noise suppression
                apm->noise_suppression()->set_level(webrtcNoiseSuppressionLevelToEnum(webrtcNoiseSuppressionLevel));
                apm->noise_suppression()->Enable(webrtcNoiseSuppressionEnabled);
                apm->gain_control()->set_compression_gain_db(compression_gain_db);
                apm->gain_control()->set_target_level_dbfs(target_level_dbfs);
                apm->gain_control()->Enable(webrtcGainControlEnabled);

                webrtc::AudioFrame frame;
                frame.num_channels_ = numChannels;
                frame.sample_rate_hz_ = SAMPLE_RATE;
                frame.samples_per_channel_ = FRAMES_PER_BUFFER;

                memcpy(frame.data_, sampleBlock, numBytes);
                if ((webrtcErr = apm->ProcessStream(&frame)) < 0) {
                        printf("Error Code: %d\n", webrtcErr); fflush(stdout);
                        return -1;
                }
                memcpy(sampleBlock, frame.data_, numBytes);

                err = Pa_WriteStream( stream, sampleBlock, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER );
                if( err ) xrun(stream, err, sampleBlock);
    }
    printf("Wire off.\n"); fflush(stdout);

    err = Pa_StopStream( stream );
    if( err != paNoError ) error1(stream, sampleBlock);

    free( sampleBlock );

    Pa_Terminate();
    return 0;

}

int xrun(PaStream *stream, int err, char* sampleBlock) {
    printf("err = %d\n", err); fflush(stdout);
    if( stream ) {
       Pa_AbortStream( stream );
       Pa_CloseStream( stream );
    }
    free( sampleBlock );
    Pa_Terminate();
    if( err & paInputOverflow )
       fprintf( stderr, "Input Overflow.\n" );
    if( err & paOutputUnderflow )
       fprintf( stderr, "Output Underflow.\n" );
    return -2;
}

void error1(PaStream *stream, char* sampleBlock) {
    free( sampleBlock );
    exit(-1);
}

void error2(PaStream *stream, int err) {
    if( stream ) {
       Pa_AbortStream( stream );
       Pa_CloseStream( stream );
    }
    Pa_Terminate();
    fprintf( stderr, "An error occured while using the portaudio stream\n" );
    fprintf( stderr, "Error number: %d\n", err );
    fprintf( stderr, "Error message: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText( err ) );
    exit(-1);
}

webrtc::NoiseSuppression::Level webrtcNoiseSuppressionLevelToEnum(int level) {
        switch (level) {
                case 0 : return webrtc::NoiseSuppression::Level::kLow;
                case 1 : return webrtc::NoiseSuppression::Level::kModerate;
                case 2 : return webrtc::NoiseSuppression::Level::kHigh;
                case 3 : return webrtc::NoiseSuppression::Level::kVeryHigh;
        }
}
```